# Group-by then row shift in each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have dataset that can be grouped with following:

```
  df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7])
```

different group sizes are

```
df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7]).size().unique()

 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

lets say I will take any group with size 4 arranged with time column ,

```
    col1     col2  time 
0   rt_2345  NaN   1:00
1   rt_2345  3.0   2:00
2   rt_2345  4.0   3:00
3   rt_2345  46.0  4:00
```

it will have 4 rows, the col2 of each group is NaN and I want to shift 1 row up for every group.

**Goal**

```
   col1      col2  time
0   rt_2345  3.0   1:00
1   rt_2345  4.0   2:00
2   rt_2345  46.0  3:00
3   rt_2345  NaN   4:00
```

This can be down with following code with gruop sizes of 2 but not valid for 3,4,5,6,7

```
.fillna(df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7])['col1'].bfill()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7])['col2'].shift(-1)
```

EDIT: If need sorting per multiple columns is possible create column `a` by first 7 values of batch and pass to [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.assign(a = df.batch.str[:7]).sort_values(['a', 'time'], 
                                                 ascending=[True, False])

df['col2'] = df.groupby('a')['col2'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: just a small query, I want to sort it as well before `.shift(-1)` `.apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'time', ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1):

We can try use `sorted` with `key` in this situation you do not need worry about how many `NaN` in the top

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(df.col1.str[:7])['col2'].apply(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.isnull) ).explode().values
df
Out[145]: 
      col1  col2  time  new
0  rt_2345   NaN  1:00    3
1  rt_2345   3.0  2:00    4
2  rt_2345   4.0  3:00   46
3  rt_2345  46.0  4:00  NaN
```